# image thumbnailer creating a black background

Tags: php, image

This is a pretty typical script to create a thumbnail. How come it keeps outputting a black canvas instead of the white I am trying to specify? Am I missing something totally obvious here?

```
<?php

$image = 'images/original/' . $_GET['image'];

$thumb = "images/thumbs/t_" . $_GET['image'];

$size = 220;

square_crop($image, $thumb, $size);

function square_crop($src_image, $dest_image, $thumb_size, $jpg_quality = 100) 
{

    // Get dimensions of existing image
    $image = getimagesize($src_image);

    // Check for valid dimensions
    if( $image[0] <= 0 || $image[1] <= 0 ) return false;

    // Determine format from MIME-Type
    $image['format'] = strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*?\//', '', $image['mime']));

    // Import image
    switch( $image['format'] ) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $image_data = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_image);
        break;
        case 'png':
            $image_data = imagecreatefrompng($src_image);
        break;
        case 'gif':
            $image_data = imagecreatefromgif($src_image);
        break;
        default:
            // Unsupported format
            return false;
        break;
    }

    // Verify import
    if( $image_data == false ) return false;

    // Calculate measurements
    if( $image[0] & $image[1] ) {
        // For landscape images
        $x_offset = ($image[0] - $image[1]) / 2;
        $y_offset = 0;
        $square_size = $image[0] - ($x_offset * 2);
    } else {
        // For portrait and square images
        $x_offset = 0;
        $y_offset = ($image[1] - $image[0]) / 2;
        $square_size = $image[1] - ($y_offset * 2);
    }

//$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

// sets background to red
//$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
//imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);

    // Resize and crop
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_size, $thumb_size);

    //make the background white
    $white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($canvas, 0,0, $white);

    if( imagecopyresampled(
        $canvas,
        $image_data,
        0,
        0,
        $x_offset,
        $y_offset,
        $thumb_size,
        $thumb_size,
        $square_size,
        $square_size)) 
    {

        // Create thumbnail
        switch( strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*\./', '', $dest_image)) ) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                return imagejpeg($canvas, $dest_image, $jpg_quality);
            break;
            case 'png':
                return imagepng($canvas, $dest_image);
            break;
            case 'gif':
                return imagegif($canvas, $dest_image);
            break;
            default:
                // Unsupported format
                return false;
            break;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the function!? I.e. where is $image_data initialized, etc.

Comment: I'm using this script slightly modifided: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2009/08/cropping-an-image-to-make-square-thumbnails-in-php/ The image is output. It's just got a black background... not white.

Comment: You're resampling the "big" image with `imagecopyresampled()` into the "small" image `$canvas`. So if the source image (`$image_data`) is black (or non-existent and you forgot to check for that) it will overwrite your white with the source image.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but since you are copying another image to the entire size of the your new thumbnail image, is any of the original canvas color in the thumbnail going to show through anyway??

Comment: @w3d it shows through because `new_thumbnail_image` may be something like 200x100 and the original canvas is always 200x200.

Comment: @SJKrK I am not sure if I follow. Are you saying that my `$canvas` is being created at say `200x200px` in white as I want and then when I put the `$image_data` into that canvas if the image is say `200x100px` its creating black in the borders by default and overlaying the white canvas?

Comment: But that isn't what the code above says... `imagecreatetruecolor()` creates a new thumbnail that is `$thumb_size` x `$thumb_size` (ie. square) and `imagecopyresampled()` copies a square region of `$image_data` into your new thumbnail that is `$thumb_size` x `$thumb_size` and starting at offset 0, 0 - so the new thumbnail background is completely covered by whatever is copied from `$image_data` ...? (I believe @SJKrK is saying the same thing.)

Comment: I think I see what you are both saying. So I need to make the script copy a rectangular region onto the canvas rather than a square.

Comment: Possibly, in order to see some of the new canvas background. Although it's not clear to us why you would want to do this, since the script appears to purposefully create a square thumbnail from any non-square image.

Comment: Yes but I get thumbnails like this: http://cl.ly/2A1O2L3k2o1a2Z092V1F and I either need white borders or it to fit completely.